# tableview not removing contents

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my code I have functionality that my tableview should be reseted and draw again.

```
    func resetList() -> Void {
        self.data.removeAll()
//        self.data = []
//        data.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        if let t = tableView {
        t.reloadData()
         }
    }

    //MARK: UITableViewDataSource
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier , for: indexPath) as? FilterCell  {
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.data.count
    }


    //MARK: UITableViewDelegate
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let c = cell as! FilterCell
        c.setFilterData(filter: self.data[indexPath.row])
        c.delegate = self
    }
```

When I am calling `resetList()` method my self.data becoming empty when I am calling `reloadData()` my tableview content still remaining old values.

What I did wrong here. Am I missed something here? What kind of problem it can be?

Comment: Did you take outlet of your tableview from storyboard to your viewcontroller ?

Comment: Yeah of course. First time data is adding successfully on my tableview, when I call reset it remains same list

Comment: self.data = () try this one @pmb

Comment: put a break point on `t.reloadData()` and see if that line got called or not, and try print `self.data.count` before return it

Comment: did you tried debugging the line where you are removing the values from the array? check that

Comment: Also where are you creating cell with values? you are just returning basic cell or custom cell without any values?

Comment: @Tj3n r.reloadData() is calling I checked

Comment: @Shabirjan  c.setFilterData(filter: self.data[indexPath.row]) here is the values

Comment: can you do teamviewer session?

Comment: Did you tried self.tableView?.reloadData() ? Instead of if let t = tableView {
        t.reloadData()
         }

Comment: Post Complete code ...

Comment: @pmb Show the declaration of tableView

Comment: Not related to the issue but `if let cell ...` will never fail and if it did hypothetically the app will crash due to the default initializer of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to clean your project and reset content & setting of the simulator

Answer (score 0):

You Want to delate all Data

so remove all value of array in your code

you want to remove one by one in your table use this code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {
            arrayDays.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace instead of this

```
if let t = tableView {
        t.reloadData()
         }
```

to

```
 self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reload the tableview. Please remove this

```
if let t = tableView {
        t.reloadData()
         }
    }
```